# ipython float slider with pandas datetime series?

Tags: python, datetime, ipython, ipywidgets

I am trying to make an interactive chart with sliders to control date and time
So I tried to do this

```
from ipywidgets import widgets, FloatSlider
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

DateList = ['2013-01-01', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-03']
ts = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(DateList))

Slider = FloatSlider(min=min(ts), max=max(ts), step=1, 
                 value=pd.Timestamp('2013-01-01'))
```

but this doesn't work?
How can I do this?

Comment: The 'float' in FloatSlider means a floating point number. I guess you'd need to make a separate `DatetimeSlider` class.

Comment: there is no DatetimeSlider class?

Comment: No, there isn't. You'd need to [make one](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Custom%20Widget%20-%20Hello%20World.html) (actually, doing it with a calendar might be easier than trying to make a date slider). Or you could just use a slider with regular numbers and convert them to dates on the Python side.